# how to make input field case insensitive?

Tags: javascript, css, html

i have made an array and i am going to find out the record, when i am going to find the record in upper case words than it is ok but when i am going to find the records with lower case letters than it is not finding the records. folloying is the script i have made.

```
if (document.getElementById('drop_down_list_1').value == "Genetic") {
    if (document.getElementById('search_input').value == "") {
        alert("Please Enter a charactor / word..");

    } else {
        var con = document.getElementById('first_div');
        var con2 = document.getElementById('first_div2');
        var char = document.getElementById('search_input').value;

        var str = '';
        var j = 0;
        var ad = ['GLARIFIDE Deadlines 2012 - 2013 Nov', 'REPRODUCTIVE VACCINES — REPRODUCTIVE CLAIMS', 'M', 'M', 'R'];
        var len = ad.length;
        //char.toLowerCase().indexOf(ad) != -1;
        var break_line = '<br>';
        for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            var str = ad[j];
            var n = str.indexOf(char);
            if (n == 0)
                con.innerHTML += '<table id="results" style="margin-top: -3px;"><tr><td>' + str + '</td><td id="td1"><a href="javascript:presenter.command(\'viewPdf\',{\'path\': \'/images/pdf/Dairy/' + j + '.pdf\'});"><img src="images/view.png" style="margin-left:250px;"></a><img src="images/email.png"></td></tr></table>' + break_line;
            break_line = '<br>';

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add more no-breaking spaces to solve this ?

Comment: I can't understand ? what do u mean?

Comment: var str = ad[j].toLowerCase(); add toLowerCase where you ought to check value

Comment: @user2244364 - what I meant was that you had a million useless `&nbsp;` but these have now been removed.

Comment: i have done this but it is not working... not finding record :(

Comment: Hi @user2244364, indent your code before posting a question please. It's unreadable now.

Comment: i have edited the code now u can easily read...

Answer (score 1):

You can't make an input field case insensitive. In javascript however you can test string equality in a case insensitive manner.

```
'HelloWorld'.toLowerCase() == 'HELLOworld'.toLowerCase() // TRUE
```